# Mysql multiple join syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to mysql and I've been having problems with this query.

Consider this query:

```
SELECT a.group_message_id, a.scheduled_date, b.message, c.phone_number, d.group_name
    FROM schedule AS a
    JOIN group_message AS b ON a.group_message_id = b.id,
    JOIN phonenumber AS c ON c.id = a.phonenumber_id,
    JOIN group_table AS d ON d.group_id = a.group_id
    WHERE a.status = 'unsent'
```

And this error message:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'JOIN phonenumber AS c ON c.id = a.phonenumber_id, JOIN
>   group_table AS d ' at line 4

I need help with what's actually wrong with the statement. Also I would really appreciate it if you can show me other and "proper" ways of doing such.

Lastly, provided that there's not enough time, is there an effective resource that I can learn from at least the basics of mysql. Please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

remove the comma on join statements,

```
JOIN group_message AS b ON a.group_message_id = b.id, -- <<== HERE
JOIN phonenumber AS c ON c.id = a.phonenumber_id,     -- <<== HERE
JOIN group_table AS d ON d.group_id = a.group_id
```

final query,

```
SELECT  a.group_message_id, 
        a.scheduled_date, 
        b.message, 
        c.phone_number, 
        d.group_name
FROM    schedule AS a
        JOIN group_message AS b 
            ON a.group_message_id = b.id
        JOIN phonenumber AS c 
            ON c.id = a.phonenumber_id
        JOIN group_table AS d 
            ON d.group_id = a.group_id
WHERE   a.status = 'unsent'
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not put commas

just check the syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

**sample syntax**

```
SELECT  column_list FROM  table1 JOIN table2 ON condition JOIN table3 ON condition WHERE condition
```